# Dynamic Hyperlink within an IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I usually don't post to sites like these but use them quite often. Thank you very much if I have popped in here just to increase my learning. I am very frustrated tonight however. Here is my challenge: I am nesting a hyperlink formula within an if statement to a digital log I have created based on whether or not their is information already entered into the log. If their is, link to the next data entry row; if their isn't, link to the first row. I created the formula successfully using multiple links however, I cannot get it to work if the formula is based on a unique number being placed in another cell (being the dynamic sheet name I want to achieve). The number is a number in an empty bin, and the sheets are named with said number. I need to use one hyperlink formula instead of hundreds so that my program has a sustainable, dynamic interface that doesn't require me to update it every time our organization adds more supply.

This is an example of the formula that works:

```
=IF('1016'!$J$7="", HYPERLINK("#'1016'!$J$7",""), HYPERLINK("#INDEX('1016'!$j$7:$j$56,MATCH(999999,'1016'!$j$7:$j$56,1)+1)",""))
```

This is what is giving me more grey hair as I speak:

```
=IF('"&X2&"'!$J$7="", HYPERLINK("#'"&X2&"'!$J$7",""), HYPERLINK("#INDEX('"&X2&"'!$j$7:$j$56,MATCH(999999,'"&X2&"'!$j$7:$j$56,1)+1)",""))
```

So the &X2&... part of the formula is basically whatever bin number a user can enter into one cell and the formula will link to the log for that bin. Their is actually a picture I have pasted into the sheets background appearing to make the picture seem like the link to click on thus my ""blank friendly name.

What is so frustrating is that both of my hyperlink conditions work just fine on their own but when I plug the same exact syntax into the logic part of my if function the sheet link will not work if the data entry log is empty. I believe I have got it to hyperlink to the false part of my if statement but, no matter what I try I cannot get the true part of my if statement to work. I either get a message telling me the link is basically invalid,a #REF, or a #VALUE error. I have moved my hashes around, my quotation marks, tried concatenate functions instead of the above syntax, drank more, took breaks, you name it, nothing seems to work. I am seriously getting livid at this point. Please help me if you can. I know it must be a simple fix. Thank you again. If I need to post my sheet I will just not sure how to do that at this point. Oh by the way, I have searched the web to no end for an answer and it appears as if I am the only one on our planet attempting to do this and our organization frowns upon any code so please, no VBA. Thank you

Comment: You are testing Cell J7 if Blank then Hyper link,,,,, &X2& doesn't looks like Sheet Name, J7 must be preceded by valid Sheet Name like your previous Formula. And Syntax to create Dynamic Hyper link is also wrong, should like =HYPERLINK("#MMP1!"&D1).

Comment: Better you post what exactly you are trying to achieve will help us to create a valid Formula.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I clarified my post further below. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, `'1016'!$J$7=""` tests whether the value of cell J7 on sheet 1016 is empty.

In your second example, `'"&X2&"'!$J$7=""` tests whether the value of cell J7 on sheet &X2& is empty, which will fail if it can't find a sheet called &X2&.

The "&" operate concatenates strings, not cell references, so to build the reference properly, you have to treat it all as a string, and sort out the quotes and concatenation accordingly: `"'" & X2 &"'!$J7"`.  However, you would then just be testing the value of one string against another.  To convert the string into a cell reference, you need to use `INDIRECT()`.  Something like this should work:

`=IF( INDIRECT("'" & X2 & "'!$J$7",TRUE), true hyperlink, false hyperlink)`

The `TRUE` parameter is required to tell INDIRECT that the string uses the A1 style of cell reference, rather than the default R1C1 referencing.

You also need to fix your dynamic hyperlinks (probably by concatenating the string "#" onto the front of your formula).

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, this works to return the false part of my formula every time:                                                                 =IF("'"&X2&"'!$J$7"="",HYPERLINK("#'"&X2&"'!$J$7",""),HYPERLINK("#INDEX('"&X2&"'!$j$7:$j$56,MATCH(999999,'"&X2&"'!$j$7:$j$56,1)+1)","") The &X2& could be used in a concatenate but isn't exactly necessary Your suggestion hyperlinks to the first data entry every time. If it is empty it gives me an invalid reference error. So the true part doesn't work correctly and the false result I want to achieve returns what I would want for true.

Comment: Thank you very much by the way, I appreciate you taking a stab at it.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify that the &X2& is just a dummy cell I am testing to see if I can type in any number, assuming that number has a sheet, and the hyperlink formula will return that sheet. So it will be the cell that they end user will type the bin number into in order to click the link and access it's sheet, whether it is X2 or A1 or whatever. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What has really got me confused is that when I isolate the TRUE hyperlink, i.e. =HYPERLINK("#'"&X2&"'!$J$7","") it works just fine but, it will not work for the life of me in the if statement. It is almost as if I have violated some unstated rule of cell references in hyperlink formulas

Comment: Both true and false hyperlinks work fine isolated. I have never seen the true or false statement invalidate the logic. sheesh!

Comment: It sounds like it is the test part of the `IF` function that is wrong, not the hyperlinks.  First, try replacing the hyperlinks with just `TRUE` and `FALSE` for debugging, to check you've got the test right.  Then put the hyperlinks back.

Comment: I think the `IF` function always returns the false formula because it is checking whether the string `"'"&X2&"'!$J$7"` is the same as the empty string `""`, which it never will be.  You need to use `INDIRECT("'"&X2&"'!$J$7", TRUE)` to turn the string into a cell reference.  Note that `HYPERLINK` is different to `IF`, and can take either a string or an actual cell reference for the link destination.  In `IF`, a string containing a reference will just be treated as a string, not the value of string cell you are referring to.

Comment: Starting my if Statement with the INDIRECT function you suggested looks to the log to see if there is a value and places the cursor on that value not the next open entry space like I need it to. If there is no value there It does nothing but give me an invalid cell reference. How do I get this If statement to recognize what I am asking it to? If there is an empty spot in one of these logs go to it,if not go to the next empty spot; furthermore I want to direct you to which log I need you to go to by typing it into X2.

Comment: Got it!, We had the Indirect syntax wrong. This is what finally worked:           =IF(INDIRECT(X2&"!$J$7")="",HYPERLINK("#'"&X2&"'!$J$7",""),HYPERLINK("#INDEX('"&X2&"'!$j$7:$j$56,MATCH(999999,'"&X2&"'!$j$7:$j$56,1)+1)",""))  Thank a ton JRI for pointing me in that direction